# Using 2D sprites and 3D models together

Tags: xna-4.0

I have gone through a few posts that talks about changing the **GraphicsDevice.BlendState** and **GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState** ([SpriteBatch & Render states](https://web.archive.org/web/20160112225515/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/shawnhar/archive/2010/06/18/spritebatch-and-renderstates-in-xna-game-studio-4-0.aspx)). . however even after changing the states .. i cant see my 3D model on the screen.. I see the model for a second before i draw my video in the background. .  If i dont play my video then i can see the 3D model ..Here is the code:

```
GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.AliceBlue);
spriteBatch.Begin();

if (player.State != MediaState.Stopped)
{
    videoTexture = player.GetTexture();
}

Rectangle screen = new Rectangle(GraphicsDevice.Viewport.X, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Y, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width, GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height);

// Draw the video, if we have a texture to draw.
if (videoTexture != null)
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(videoTexture, screen, Color.White);

    if (Selected_underwater == true)
    {
        spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "MaxX , MaxY" + maxWidth + "," + maxHeight, new Vector2(400, 10), Color.Red);
        spriteBatch.Draw(kinectRGBVideo, new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.Draw(butterfly, handPosition, Color.White);

        foreach (AnimatedSprite a in aSprites)
        {
            a.Draw(spriteBatch);
        }                       
    }

    if(Selected_planet == true)
    {            
        spriteBatch.Draw(kinectRGBVideo, new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100), Color.White);
        spriteBatch.Draw(butterfly, handPosition, Color.White);
        spriteBatch.Draw(videoTexture,screen,Color.White);

        GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque;
        GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
        GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.LinearWrap;

        foreach (_3DModel m in Solar)
        {
            m.DrawModel();
        }
    }
    spriteBatch.End();
```

Comment: Your spriteBatch.Begin() and spriteBatch.End() do not occur in the same scope, that's a bad idea. You should really have your Begin() inside the 'if (videoTexture != null)' block.

Comment: Im using themes..thats why I have these bool statements.. If theme selected then do this . . or do that ..So i thought a general sprite.Begin() and sprite.End() should help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you are having is because `SpriteBatch`, by default<sup>[1]</sup>, buffers all rendering until `End` is called.

It's not really a problem with render states. The states you specify in `Begin` (or the default states if you specify nothing) are only set during `End`.

What is happening is that, by calling `End` after drawing your model, **you are rendering all your sprites over the top of your model**.

Just split your rendering into multiple batches, or call `End` earlier (whichever suits) and it should work correctly. Be sure that `Begin`/`End` pairs always match up!

---

[1] : Except in `SpriteSortMode.Immediate`, which does everything, well, immediately. It sets states in `Begin` and draws a sprite for each `Draw`. Because of this it can't do batching and so is generally slower.

Answer (score 2):

spriteBatch.Begin();

Defaults to SortMethod.Deferred. You can't change render states in between a begin/end pair unless its SortMethod.Immediate. So the below is not doing anything.

```
GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque;
GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.LinearWrap;
```

The simple fix is to end the spritebatch then call the above code before you render your 3D stuff. Ex:

```
if(Selected_planet == true)
{            
    spriteBatch.Draw(kinectRGBVideo, new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100), Color.White);
    spriteBatch.Draw(butterfly, handPosition, Color.White);
    spriteBatch.Draw(videoTexture,screen,Color.White);
}

spriteBatch.End();

if(Selected_planet == true)
{ 
    GraphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque;
    GraphicsDevice.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;
    GraphicsDevice.SamplerStates[0] = SamplerState.LinearWrap;

    foreach (_3DModel m in Solar)
    {
        m.DrawModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution will fix the problem, but your reasoning is incorrect. It's perfectly acceptable - and functional - to change states inside a `Begin`/`End` pair (it just doesn't affect the batch itself). See my answer.

Comment: ClassicThunder.. im still awaiting ur reply for .3DS extension i have already added my links and models in tht thread